# Belkin device runs Linux, how can I create my own custom firmware for it?

Tags: linux, hacking, firmware

The Belkin N300 F9K1002 firmware is located [here](http://cache-www.belkin.com/support/dl/F9K1002_WW_1.00.14.bin). It does not appear to be encrypted. How can I upload my own custom Linux firmware to this device. How would I go about hacking it?

Comment: You can run [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/) on it, provided you [patch it on your own](http://manojpi.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/openwrt-on-belkin-share-max-n300.html).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Can a trx file be uploaded from the web interface or do I need some type of serial connector?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the firmware upload process of a specific device rather than software architecture and design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On most other routers I have used, there's an admin console somewhere that has an "Update Firmware" link.  You click that, it opens a file browser window, you point it at the location of your firmware file and it takes care of everything.  You'll have to dissect the factory firmware package to see how it's structured, but it shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to add or replace stuff.